# Buildroot package override but no image generated

Tags: linux-device-driver, qemu, buildroot

I'm facing an issue to get the final image for `qemu`. In order to accelerate my dev I'm using override (`PACKAGENAME_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR =/path/to/local` with `PACKAGENAME-rebuild`, I see it takes the new changes from the local_repo because I am able to see all the new generated kernel modules under `buildroot/output/target` but when I load the `qemu` the filesystem loaded is the previous image builded from the full build (from the remote repo). After checking the `buildroot/output/images` I see the `rootfs.ext*` with a modified timestamp which matches the OVERRIDE rebuild time, but the `Image` has the timestamp from the previous full build (remote). How can I generate the Image in order to have the latest changes pulled from the local repo (override).
I have tried `make linux-rebuild` but still has the previous filesystem.

> Note: I have enable `BR2_CCACHE=y` just in case it matters